# Changes from WooCommerce 2.x and 3.x

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem since I had update many installation of WooCommerce from 2.x to most recent 3.x version.

I've created a simple plugin in PHP to send some information from WooCommerce to an invoice generator system.

Everything was good with 2.x but now...

---

```
$order = new WC_Order($orderId);
$user = $order->get_user();
$items = $order->get_items();
```

---

```
$articolo = array( 
    "quantita" => $item['item_meta']['_qty'][0], 
    "codice" => $item['item_meta']['_product_id'][0], 
    "prezzo_netto" => ($item['item_meta']['_line_subtotal'][0]/$item['item_meta']['_qty'][0]), 
);
```

---

```
"indirizzo_via" => $order->shipping_address_1, 
"indirizzo_citta" => $order->shipping_city, 
"indirizzo_provincia" => $order->shipping_state, 
"paese" => WC()->countries->countries[ $order->shipping_country ],
```

---

```
"lista_pagamenti" => array( 
    array( 
        "importo"=> number_format($order->get_total(),2), 
        "metodo"=> $order->payment_method_title, 
    ) 
)
```

---

I think i had to change something in the method to call the information from $order and $item but i can't find the new references :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"indirizzo_via" => $order->get_shipping_address_1(), 
"indirizzo_citta" => $order->get_shipping_city(), 
"indirizzo_provincia" => $order->get_shipping_state(), 
"paese" => WC()->countries->countries[ $order->get_shipping_country() ],
```

Call your product/order object like **get_**object_name()